# How to custom array mapping using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary

I have an array as below. The atrributes are order_id, qty, sell_price, product_name and merchant_name for every array. I want to map based on the same order_id and change the attributes become to array if the same order_id greater than 1.

```
[items:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [order_id] => 1
                [qty] => 1
                [sell_price] => 45000.00
                [product_name] => Omni Bars Cokelat Kelapa
                [merchant_name] => Health & Co.
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [order_id] => 1
                [qty] => 1
                [sell_price] => 55000.00
                [product_name] => Trim Eats Strawberry Banana Cream Overnight Oats
                [merchant_name] => Trim Eats
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [order_id] => 1
                [qty] => 1
                [sell_price] => 28000.00
                [product_name] => Everything Banana Keripik Pisang Rumput Laut
                [merchant_name] => EverythingBanana
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [order_id] => 2
                [qty] => 1
                [sell_price] => 35000.00
                [product_name] => Naked Bar Banana Nutter
                [merchant_name] => Naked Foodss
            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [order_id] => 3
                [qty] => 1
                [sell_price] => 200000.00
                [product_name] => Health & Co. Paket Detoks 1 Hari
                [merchant_name] => Health & Co.
            )

        [5] => stdClass Object
            (
                [order_id] => 3
                [qty] => 1
                [sell_price] => 38000.00
                [product_name] => Health & Co. Paket 3 Botol Holy Kale
                [merchant_name] => Health & Co.
            )

   )
```

I want to map the array to something like this with the key is order_id.

```
   [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [qty] => [1,1,1]
            [sell_price] => [45000.00, 55000.00, 28000.00]
            [product_name] => [Omni Bars Cokelat Kelapa, Trim Eats Strawberry Banana Cream Overnight Oats, Everything Banana Keripik Pisang Rumput Laut]
            [merchant_name] => [Health & Co, Trim Eats, EverythingBanana]
        )
   [2] => so on....
```

I stuck on it. Please help me.

Comment: Do you already have any code written you could share with us? This seems like a rather easy question to solve.

Comment: Do you actually need to combine it like this? It seems it would be better if you'd keep all the product's attributes together, rather than splitting them over 4 arrays..

Comment: Yes, sure. I need to combine like this because I want to generate the data in excel.

Answer (score 0):

Look this solution:

```
//$data - your array

$result = [];
foreach ($data as $item) {
    $result[$item['order_id']]['qty'][] = $item['qty'];
    $result[$item['order_id']]['sell_price'][] = $item['sell_price'];
    $result[$item['order_id']]['product_name'][] = $item['product_name'];
    $result[$item['order_id']]['merchant_name'][] = $item['merchant_name'];
}

// $result your result array
```

Comment: It is still wrong. The expectation array based on the same order_id.

Comment: Every items are grouped by order_id. What do you want? Do you want array of objects instead of a nested array?